# SQLAlchemy Error on insert

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geoalchemy

I am trying to add a point with GeoAlchemy 2. However I am getting getting error on insert action saying

---sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(39.9130572,3" <-- parse error at position 18 within geometry
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO spots (name, geom) VALUES (%(name)s, ST_GeomFromEWKT(%(geom)s)) RETURNING spots.id'] [parameters: {'name': 'testspot', 'geom': 'POINT(39.9130572,32.7892743)'}]---

I check the spots table and its geometry appears as point.Could anyone tell me where is the problem ?

class Spot(Base):
    **tablename** = 'spots'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    geom = Column(Geometry('POINT'))

Spot.**table**.create(engine)

if not session.query(Spot).filter_by(name='testspot').first():
    spot = Spot(name='testspot', geom='POINT(39.9130572,32.7892743)')
    print(spot.geom)
    session.add(spot)
    session.commit()
else:
    spot=session.query(Spot).filter_by(name='testspot').first()

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the comma between coordinates in 'geom':'POINT(39.9130572 32.7892743)'